# Cannot access Wordpress site after installing theme from Repository

Tags: wordpress

I recently installed the [BluePrintQ Draft Wordpress theme](https://en-au.wordpress.org/themes/blueprintq-draft/) via the admin panel from the Wordpress repository (not from an unknown external site) - and immediately afterwards I was presented with the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/users1/i/ivashka075/domains/xn--j1abhbci.xn--p1ai/wp-content/themes/blueprintq-draft/packages/ski.web/controls/ski.wp.customizer.php on line 41
```

Now I am effectively locked out and can't get back in.

*NOTE: This question was originally in Russian and has since been translated to English*

Comment: ты бы лучше спросил на русском сайте `ru.stackoverflow.com` =)

Comment: Can you translate my answer for Сергей ?

Comment: yep. already doing this =)

Comment: I added a rough english translation of the question but it has not been approved: Hello! Please help solve my problem! After installing a theme from the list of available themes from the Wordpress repository in the admin area (rather than from other sources), I've lost access to my site and now gives the error message below: etc

Comment: I've said him how to recover access to admin area =)

Comment: @DamienSugden, your translation is pretty close to the source, btw.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the reason this is failing on your server is that you need to be running `PHP` version `5.40` or later for that theme to work.

Line 41 of the code on that theme tries to use a method of code reuse called `Traits`. This method is not available on versions older than 5.40.

Either upgrade your `PHP` version or find another theme :(

If you are unable to get back into your site, perform a backup and connect to your installation via FTP and as quick hack, delete the blueprintq-draft theme's folder.

Find This Folder:

`/home/users1/i/ivashka075/domains/xn--j1abhbci.xn--p1ai/wp-content/themes/blueprintq-draft/`

and move it elsewhere or just delete that folder `"blueprintq-draft"` and its subfolders.

MAKE SURE YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING WHEN DELETING.

Comment: Если перевести в двух словах, то ты выбрал тему, которой нужен `php` версии `5.4.х` или выше, потому что в ней используются `trait'ы`. Поэтому тебе предлагают либо поменять версию `php`, либо выбрать другую тему. Но, судя по всему, ты поменять из админки не сможешь, поэтому попробуй через хостинг поменять версию `php`. А если не можешь поменять, попробуй удалить (а лучше перенести в другое место) папку с темой `blueprintq-draft` через `FTP`. Тогда админка должна заработать.

Comment: DamienSugden, agreed =)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :) подскажи пожалуйста с помощью какой программы можно попасть в ftp. программа fillezilla не подключается, говорит о критической ошибке и о не способности соедениться с сервером